# Special keyword as {id} in URI to identify special resource

Tags: rest, api, design-patterns

I'm designing a REST API, and have a collections of items, just call it PROD;

PROD has its typicals endpoints that accept the typical operations (POST, GET and so on)

```
api/prods/AAAAA
api/prods/BBBBB
api/prods/CCCCC
```

Now, I'd like to identify a specific item called the **current** PROD;

The current PROD is one of the items choosed by a logic that resides completely in the backend, and should accept all the HTTP operations;

How should i create an endpoint to identify it?

is this a good choice?

```
api/prods/current
```

then, in the backend i transparently apply the operations to whatever item i consider **current**.

I'm trying to implements this solution but doesn't seems perfectly right.

Any ideas on how to handle this scenario right?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with having a path that points to the current PROD, but `api/prods/current` looks ambiguous.  Is it the current prod, or the prod named 'current'?

Maybe `apis/currentprod` would be better, or `apis/specialprods/current`, or something else that's obviously not prod-by-name.

Be careful, however, because it will probably not be OK just to redirect requests from `currentprod` to `prods/whatever`, because HTTP headers and operations that control caching (ETag, Last-Modified, If-Modified-Since), etc., will not be correct when values from one target are used on another.  This could result in clients using cached data from the wrong PROD.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, very appreciated. Actually I like both apis/currentprod and apis/specialprods/current. I didn'nt even think about the caching problem, but I think I can manage it somehow.